# Pandas query API not working as intended, how to improve/make it work

Tags: pandas

I am filtering pandas rows as below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'roll_Call': [32041, 60164, 164989, 179741, 231414],
    'name': ['Cozy Kim', 'Sam Juday', 'Jessica M', 'Ajay Kim Jong', 'Kim Jong'],
    'std': [2, 3, 1, 1, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df[~((df['name'].str.contains('kim', case=False)) &
          (df['name'].str.contains('jong', case=False)) &
          (df['std'] <= 1))]
```

When I try to do the same using .query API it doesn't work, is it possible to mimic the filtering above using .query ?

For Example (below doesn't work):

```
df.query("'Kim' in name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.contains` as well:

```
out = df.query("~((std<=1) & name.str.contains('kim', case=False) & name.str.contains('jong', case=False))")
```

Output:

```
   roll_Call       name  std
0      32041   Cozy Kim    2
1      60164  Sam Juday    3
2     164989  Jessica M    1
```

##### other example

Assuming:

```
   roll_Call           name  std
0      32041       Cozy Kim    1
1      32042       Cozy Kim    2
2      60164      Sam Juday    3
3     164989      Jessica M    1
4     179741  Ajay Kim Jong    1
5     231414       Kim Jong    1
6     231415     Kim Y Jong    2
```

The set of conditions provided in the question give:

```
   roll_Call        name  std
0      32041    Cozy Kim    1
1      32042    Cozy Kim    2
2      60164   Sam Juday    3
3     164989   Jessica M    1
6     231415  Kim Y Jong    2
```

In contrast `df.query(expr="~(std.le(1) & name.str.contains('kim|jong', case=False))")` outputs:

```
   roll_Call        name  std
1      32042    Cozy Kim    2
2      60164   Sam Juday    3
3     164989   Jessica M    1
6     231415  Kim Y Jong    2
```

Comment: Latest version (2.0.3) NB. I added the missing `~` which I hadn't seen.